# What guarantees do we have when verifying the sender's identity (in SmartPy)?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

When we check the address that called the current entry point e.g. in SmartPy:

```
sp.verify(self.data.authorizedAddr == sp.sender)
```

What guarantees do we have? For example, is it possible for someone else to have called the entry point?

Answer (score 3):

You are guaranteed (if the crypto behind Tezos is not broken) that the person who signed the transaction knew the corresponding private key (in case of an implicit account) so, for all reasonable purposes, you should be good.

Comment: Okay great so just to confirm, there are no caveats with delegating signing responsibility or anything like that? Thanks!

Comment: When sender is a tz account, the corresponding user signed the transaction. When sender is a contract, there's no signing involved in the corresponding sub-transaction but a verification from the contract (which may verify or not that a particular tz account signed a transaction).